# Having TCP error when trying to access a service via HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I have Class Library type project called "HelloWorldService" that has this interface:

```
namespace HelloWorldService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IHelloWorldService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetMessage(string message);
    }
}
```

And this class:

```
namespace HelloWorldService
{
    public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService 
    {
        public string GetMessage(string message)
        {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a web site in my solution and imported the reference of the "HelloWorldService" in it.
So, this website(called HelloWorldLocal) has only a bin folder with "HelloWorldService.dll", "HelloWorldService.pdb" and outside the bin folder there's this web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
             relativeAddress="./HelloWorldLocal/HelloWorldLocal.svc" service="HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Now, I'm publishing this website on IIS via Visual Studio under "Default Web Site/HelloWorldLocal" and when I try to access `http://localhost/HelloWorldLocal/HelloWorldService.svc` I get this TCP error:

```
Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].
```

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by opening IIS manager, clicking with the right button on the website, then selected Manage Application > Advanced Settings.

Then on the window that opens, there's an "Enabled Protocols" property with only http. I added "net.tcp" and it worked.

No idea why but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following line

```
<add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
         relativeAddress="./HelloWorldLocal/HelloWorldLocal.svc" service="HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService"/>
```

to

```
<add factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory"
         relativeAddress="HelloWorldLocal.svc" service="HelloWorldService.HelloWorldService"/>
```

Comment: One more thing you need to add is                    <protocolMapping>
    <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>

Comment: Did that, but nothing changed yet :/